# What are some standard software stacks for financial data collection, storage and visualization?

Tags: database, visualization

I'm looking for the fastest way to get up-and-running collecting time-series data (mainly through scraping and through 3rd party APIs), storing it and visualizing it on a dashboard with graphs.

I'd like to create custom dashboards for each of the markets I'm invested in, which show everything from asset prices, to twitter sentiment, to fundamentals and technicals.

TradingView.com is great for technical analysis, but I am looking to monitor much more in-depth datasets which it does not offer.

I am currently looking at the TICK stack to get started (https://influxdata.com/). However, it seems much more geared towards IoT and server monitoring.

Are there any other industry standard software stacks available for this application?